# What element to use onkeydown attribute on?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to get run a function when I press the `w` key, I found some solutions but was not able to figure our where to place that code. Also I want it to be executed no matter when I press `w` as long as I'm on the same web page.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <input type="text" onkeydown="keyPressed()">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="screen">
            
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function keyPressed() {
    // this doesn't run.
}
```

If I made a mistake then please tell me it and if I didn't make a mistake why doesn't it work?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run? It doesn't do anything. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsbin.com/qumununari/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Quentin i debugged it before hand and i had a console.log("test") inside the function and nothing got outputed no matter what button i pressed

Comment: Is your problem that the function doesn't get called when you *focus the input and press a key* or that the function doesn't get called **only** when you **don't** focus the input before you press a key?

Comment: @Quentin Well the functions never runs so i think it is due to the tag in the HTML file that is wrong. the function does runs if i call it in the script of course

Comment: Please address the two specific cases I asked about instead of just repeating your original "doesn't work" statement.

Comment: @Quentin If i call the function in the javascript file the function does run but if i try to call it with the tag in the html file it doesn't get called and i know that because i used a console.log() in the function

Comment: You still aren't addressing the two specific cases I mentioned in my earlier comment. Read it again. I'm asking about where the focus is.

Comment: @Quentin i didn't know what you meant by focus  so i just assumed that it was that sorry if this sound stupid

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus - If the cursor is blinking in the input and typing makes characters appear in the input, then the input has focus.

Comment: @Quentin sorry for responding so long later but there was a power surge and the internet went but now i got internet again and i think i may know why i didn't work. i don't want it to be a box to insert a key i want it to be so that when i press a key it will call the function not when i type in the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to "listen" for a keydown event and specifically listen for w.

Below is code that does this without an input.
You will have to click in the window to make it work (on a web page it should work without needing to click in the window.)

```js
function ready(callbackFunction){
    if(document.readyState != 'loading')
        callbackFunction(ev)
    else
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callbackFunction)
}

ready(ev => {
    console.log('DOM is ready.');
// code above checks that the DOM is loaded and ready

    // addEventListener on the window and listen for keydown

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

        // Next 4 lines listen for the key and print it to the screen, not really needed.
        let str = "KeyboardEvent: key='" + event.key + "' | code='" + event.code + "'";
        let el = document.createElement("span");
        el.innerHTML = str + "<br/>";
        document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(el);
        
        // this listens for w, add your function in here.
        if (event.key == "w") {
            alert('You pressed lowercase w');
        }

    }, true);

 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <title>My Project</title>
</head>

<body>



<main>
Click in this window to make active. <br>
Then keydown and the key & keycode will show. <br>
keydown lowercase w and it will alert.
<div id="screen"> </div>
</main>

</body>

</html>
```